# Render Jade like an Angular partial

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, pug

I study the MEAN conceptions by this [video course](http://pluralsight.com/training/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=building-angularjs-nodejs-apps-mean&highlight=) by Joe Eames. 
This course interesting because teach how to use JADE templates as partials instead of HTML.

```
\bin
\node_modules
\public
    \app
        \main
            someCntr.js
            otherCntr.js
        main.js
\server
    \views
        \partials
            main.jade
            featured-courses.jade
            new-courses.jade
```

And all was going well until he moved this jade templates from `\views\includes` to `\public\app\main` and  `\public\app\courses` in his Express 3.4. This trick does not work in my Express 4

his server.js file before

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/server/views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.get('/partials/:partialPath', function(req, res) {
    res.render('partials/' + req.params.partialPath);
});
```

and after moving

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/server/views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.get('/partials/*', function(req, res) {
  res.render('public/app/' + req.params);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to update jade to it's latest version:

http://expressjs.com/guide/migrating-4.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm studying this course too, and I come to same problem...
The solution is to use req.params[0]. In server.js file the route to partials views like this:

insted of

```
app.get('/partials/*', function(req, res) {
  res.render('public/app/' + req.params);
});
```

write:

```
app.get('/partials/*', function(req, res) {
  res.render('../../public/app/' + req.params[0]);
});
```